# Make action bar "up navigation" trigger dialogfragment

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar, android-dialogfragment

Can I make the action bar's "up" navigation trigger a confirmation dialogfragment that says "Are you sure you would like to go back?"

Comment: Yes, you can. However your users will probably find it annoying.

Comment: Or they might find it protective, as navigating back resets the model state.  Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Sure, I'll make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intercepting the `up` ActionBar button press is trivial because everything is done through `onOptionsItemSelected`. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html), recommends that you use `android.R.id.home` to go up with `NavUtils` (provided that you set the metadata for the parent activity so `NavUtils` doesn't throw an Exception, etc):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Your `DialogFragment` should offer an confirmation to actually go back. Since you're now working with the `Fragment` and not the `Activity`, you're going to want to pass `getActivity()` to `NavUtils`.

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
```

and change `onOptionsItemSelected()` to

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        new ConfirmationDialog().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirmation_dialog");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

`ConfirmationDialog` is your custom `DialogFragment`.

Note that for this example, I am using the `support` `Fragment` APIs,. If you are not, make sure to change `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Thank you!!  I got my solution working in 20 seconds after your post.  The trick was understanding that the up navigation can be caught inside onOptionsItemSelected() with case of android.R.id.home.

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't sure how detailed to be, so answering took longer than simply telling you to use `home` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pressing the "up" button just calls the option menu callback with R.id.home. So you could just grab that, display the dialog box and if the positive button is pressed call NavUtils.navigateUpTo().